# React router doesn't reload components on change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

When route change from project to home the menu component still on.
I just want it to destroy with changing of the routes and remount on the top of next route.

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Home from "./Routes/Home";
import Project from "./Routes/ProjectRoute";
import Store from "./Store";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route element={<Home />} index />
      <Route path="/:project" element={<Project />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

root.render(
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </Provider>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import TopScroll from "./Components/TopScroll";
import "./Style/app.scss";
import { menu } from "./NavSlice";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import Menu from "./Components/Menu";

function App() {
  const menuOpened = useSelector(menu);

  useEffect(() => {
    menuOpened
      ? document.body.classList.add("stop-scrolling")
      : document.body.classList.remove("stop-scrolling");
  }, [menuOpened]);

  return (
    <Box position={"relative"} overflow="hidden">
      <TopScroll />
      <Header />
      {menuOpened && <Menu />}
      <Outlet />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`useNavigate` to move to next route functionally

```
onClick={() => {
  if (pathname === "/") {
    return null;
  }
  navigate("/", { replace: true });
}}
```

**I tried `NavLink` but still the same issue**

I tried to remove the Menu component from App.js and rendering it inside each of home and project mainRoutes but it still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the post correctly it seems you want to close the menu when navigating from one route to another.

It looks like the menu is "controlled" by some Redux state.

```
function App() {
  const menuOpened = useSelector(menu); // <-- controlled by Redux state

  useEffect(() => {
    menuOpened
      ? document.body.classList.add("stop-scrolling")
      : document.body.classList.remove("stop-scrolling");
  }, [menuOpened]);

  return (
    <Box position={"relative"} overflow="hidden">
      <TopScroll />
      <Header />
      {menuOpened && <Menu />}
      <Outlet />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

What I'd suggest then is to dispatch the "closeMenu" action when a menu item is selected and the app is navigating to another route.

Menu

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { closeMenu } from '../../NavSlice'; // <-- check path
...

const dispatch = useDispatch();

...

onClick={() => {
  dispatch(closeMenu()); // <-- close menu then handle navigation

  if (pathname === "/") {
    return null;
  }

  navigate("/", { replace: true });
}}
```

Comment: I got misunderstanding with redux I've just been using this for only 2 weeks so I dispatched the close menu action but I didn't have see your answer till now thanks sir I'm really appreciate your contribution